# Well-posedness of weak formulation using SPUG method for advection-dominated equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, sobolev-spaces

Consider the weak form using the SUPG method:
$$(u_t, v+\delta b \cdot \nabla v) + a(u,v)  = (f, v+\delta  b \cdot \nabla v ),$$
where $a(u,v) = (b \cdot \nabla u, \delta b  \cdot \nabla v )$. How to prove the well-posedness of this weak form.

If we have test function $v$ instead of $\delta b \cdot \nabla v$, one can use a coercivity-like argument. As follows:
By multiplying test function $v = u$ in above equation to obtain that
\begin{equation}\label{stfe20}
(u_{t},u+\delta b \cdot \nabla u)+a(u,u+\delta b \cdot \nabla u)=(f,u+\delta b \cdot \nabla u),
\end{equation}
which is reduced to
\begin{align}\label{stfe21}
\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dt}\|u\|^{2}_{L^{2}(\Omega)}+\delta\|b \cdot \nabla v\|^{2}_{L^{2}(\Omega)} 
+\||b \cdot \mathbf{n}|^{1/2}v\|^{2}_{L^{2}(\partial \Omega)}\\[4pt]
\leq \left|(f,u+\delta b \cdot \nabla u)\right|+\left|\delta(u_{t}, b \cdot \nabla u)\right|,
\end{align}
Next, we estimate right-hand side terms as follows:
\begin{align}\label{stfe202}
    \left|(f,u)\right| \leq 2\|f\|^{2}_{L^{2}(\Omega)} + \dfrac{1}{8} \|u\|^{2}_{L^{2}(\Omega)} 
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}\label{stfe203}
    \left|\delta(f, b \cdot \nabla u)\right| \leq 2\delta\|f\|^{2}_{L^{2}(\Omega)} + \dfrac{\delta}{8} \|b \cdot \nabla u\|^{2}_{L^{2}(\Omega)}. 
\end{align}
In a similar way, the second term is bounded by
\begin{align}\label{stfe204}
    \left|\delta(u_{t}, b \cdot \nabla u)\right| \leq 2\delta\|u_{t}\|^{2}_{L^{2}(\Omega)} + \dfrac{\delta}{8} \|b \cdot \nabla u\|^{2}_{L^{2}(\Omega)}. 
\end{align}
Now, how we do manage this last term $\delta\|u_{t}\|^{2}_{L^{2}(\Omega)}$, while using all RHS terms in original bilinear form? All other terms are manageable.